# How do I compare all tables with nonzero rowcounts (in an archive db) with tables of the same name in the line of business db?

Tags: sql-server, join, optimization, ssms

(Full Disclosure: I am a software tester who is out of my depth. Because I am unable to get a definitive answer from the developer due to the necessary independence of the test team, I have to figure this out myself.)

This query gives me a rowcount of all the tables in the archive db:

query0:

```
SELECT sc.NAME + '.' + ta.NAME tablename,
   Sum(pa.rows)            rowcnt
FROM   ARC_DB.sys.tables ta
   INNER JOIN ARC_DB.sys.partitions pa
           ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id
   INNER JOIN ARC_DB.sys.schemas sc
           ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE  ta.is_ms_shipped = 0
   AND pa.index_id IN ( 1, 0 )
GROUP  BY sc.NAME,
      ta.NAME
ORDER  BY Sum(pa.rows) DESC
```

query1:

```
SELECT sc.NAME + '.' + ta.NAME tablename,
   Sum(pa.rows)            rowcnt
FROM   LOB_DB.sys.tables ta
   INNER JOIN LOB_DB.sys.partitions pa
           ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id
   INNER JOIN LOB_DB.sys.schemas sc
           ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE  ta.is_ms_shipped = 0
   AND pa.index_id IN ( 1, 0 )
GROUP  BY sc.NAME,
      ta.NAME
ORDER  BY Sum(pa.rows) DESC
```

But how can I use this to compare the ARC_DB table names and row counts to the line of business (LOB_DB) db, whose tables have much larger rowcounts? Note: I do not care about those LOB_DB tables whose ARC_DB counterparts have no rows. Could I do something like giving query0 a variable in the "from" clause, giving query1 a variable through an inner join, then comparing one variable to another? Does that make sense?

Any help is super appreciated. I am on a deadline, and will respond immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with t1 as (
SELECT sc.NAME + '.' + ta.NAME tablename,
   Sum(pa.rows)            rowcnt
FROM   ARC_DB.sys.tables ta
   INNER JOIN ARC_DB.sys.partitions pa
           ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id
   INNER JOIN ARC_DB.sys.schemas sc
           ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE  ta.is_ms_shipped = 0
   AND pa.index_id IN ( 1, 0 )
   and pa.rows > 0
GROUP  BY sc.NAME,
      ta.NAME
)
select t1.tablename, t1.rowcnt, t2.rowcnt, t1.rowcnt-t2.rowcnt as diff
from t1
join (
SELECT sc.NAME + '.' + ta.NAME tablename,
   Sum(pa.rows)            rowcnt
FROM   LOB_DB.sys.tables ta
   INNER JOIN LOB_DB.sys.partitions pa
           ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id
   INNER JOIN LOB_DB.sys.schemas sc
           ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE  ta.is_ms_shipped = 0
   AND pa.index_id IN ( 1, 0 )
GROUP  BY sc.NAME,
      ta.NAME
) as t2 on t2.tablename = t1.tablename
```